# JMeter Modify the GET response to use in PUT

Tags: jmeter

I have two requests, the first one is GET, second is PUT. I should receive the response data from GET request, modify it a little bit and send with PUT request. So far I managed to do all, except modifying the response data.

For GET request I use Regular Expression Extractor as Preprocessor:
[image: parsing get]

And currently I send the PUT request without modifying the data:
[image: sending put]

JSON structure:

```
{
  "property1" : 1,
  "property2" : "2",
  "innerPropery" : {
    "innerProperty1" : "value1",
    "innerProperty2" : "value2",
    "innerProperty3" : "value3"
  }
}
```

I should change the innerProperty2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it without Regular Expression Extractor interim step.

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the `getForm` request
2. Choose `groovy` in the "Language" drop-down
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
   import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

   def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
   def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)

   def builder = new JsonBuilder(json)
   builder.content.property2 = '2.1'

   vars.put("response", builder.toPrettyString())
   ```
4. In `saveForm` request use `${response}` as the request body

References:

- [Parsing and Producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do this via BeanShell PostProcessor. First I have added a new BeanShell PostProcessor: click right button on getFrom, Add -> Post Processors -> BeanShell PostProcessor. After that I opened the reated BeanSChell and have written the following code in Script field:

```
responseString = vars.get("response");
log.info("Received response: " + responseString);
responseString = responseString.replace("\"prop1\" : \"value2\"", "\"prop1\" : \"value2.1\"");
log.info("Response to send: " + responseString);
vars.put("modifiedResponse", responseString);
```

In Parameters field I have written:

```
response
```

Finally, I changed for PUT request the body from

```
${response}
```

to

```
${modifiedResponse}
```